# Ninject equivalent of Unity RegisterInstance method

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, unity-container, ninject

Does Ninject have and equivalent method for unity's registerinstance.

I want to create a mock object and register it.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's the simple answer

```
Bind<IMyType>().ToConstant<MyType>(new MyType());
```

So here's an example using Moq:

```
var mock = new Mock<IMyType>();
//Setup your mock expectations / etc here.
//...
Bind<IMyType>().ToConstant(mock.Object);
```

Bonus answer:

I find that some people are actually just looking to create a singleton instance of a particular class, rather than actually creating it themselves (this allows the object to be created when something requests it, rather than when you are building your container).  This is done like this:

```
Bind<IMyType>.To<MyType>().Using<SingletonBehavior>();
```

In your case, since you said the word "mock", I'd assume you'd want the first rather than the second answer, but it's a good thing to know.

Comment: using Moq...

var mock = new Mock<IMyType>();

Bind<IMyType>().ToConstant(mock);

ConstantProvider would create an instance of Mock<IMyType>, which is not compatible with the requested service

Comment: you need to pass in MyMock.Object, not the mock itself :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what sort of mocking tool, if any, or version of Ninject you're using; however, it's worth mentioning that Ninject 2 has an extension for it that provides integration with Moq -- http://github.com/enkari/ninject.moq.

I realize this doesn't directly answer your question, [Anderson's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258498/ninject-equivalent-of-unity-registerinstance-method/1258578#1258578) does that well, but thought it might be relevant anyway.

Comment: Nice! That might be really what he is looking for.

Comment: Yeah, looks good -- haven't used it myself yet, but looking to do so at soon.